# GWT multi-module app not compiling when dependent module is changed

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have a pure-Java project (A) and a GWT project (B) set up as a multi-module GWT project as described [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html).

When I run `mvn install` for the first time, A compiles, then B performs a full GWT compile.  However if I change anything in A, then B does not compile as I would expect; I get

```
[INFO] <module> is up to date. GWT compilation skipped.
```

If I enable `<force>true</force` then it does compile and I can see my changes.

How can I make my project automatically compile when a dependent module has changed, and skip compilation if nothing has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if incremental builds are broken in the gwt-maven-plugin, just like in almost every Maven plugin out there: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Incremental+Builds

There's a note about it in the sources: https://github.com/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/d6464421d9ceb815db2d594ae0bf2d9ca07a1643/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt/shell/CompileMojo.java#L390

I tend to agree that, the maven-compiler-plugin being broken in a similar way, you should do a `clean` anyway in this situation. Alternatively, if you know the change is *compatible* with your code and shouldn't change the output of the maven-compiler-plugin, then force the GWT compilation by passing `-Dgwt.compiler.force` on the command line.

Comment: Hmm.  I was looking for a way to make the compilation just happen when the core project A had been changed, and not if not.  I compile my GWT project "in the background" as part of an xcode build, and would like everything to be compiled only when needed.  I guess my use case is not the same as most.

Comment: I think we all want a working incremental build, it just isn't there yet in Maven (assuming it can be fixed, which I'm doubtful about)

Comment: @funkybro Depends how you code your build file: there's no (official) GWT Compiler task so you use a `<java>` task to run the compiler which won't do any staleness check; you have to do the check _by hand_ using an `<uptodate>` task or similar.